# UITextView input into string, updated as one is typing and displayed into a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, uitextfield, uilabel

This is what I am trying to do with the `iOS 8 SDK` and need help with. These steps outline the process I am trying to achieve.

1. There is a `UITextView`. The user types in his/her search terms.
2. These search terms are allocated in the form of a string. This string incorporates the search terms into a URL. **This updates as the user types.**
3. The string is displayed in a `UILabel` on the user's screen. **This updates as the user types.**

In my `ViewController.h`, I have created a `UITextField` and `UILabel` and linked them up to the `Main.storyboard` accordingly.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *keywords;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *link;
```

This is when I am unsure of what to do. The application must detect when the text input changes to alter the string and display this updated string in the label. I have tried using this method in my `ViewController.m` but it fails to work.

```
[self.keywords addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

This is how I am trying to allocate the text input into a string and display it on screen (in the `viewDidLoad` - am I meant to be using a `NSString` as done or a `NSMutableString`)

```
NSString *terms = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/?q=%@", self.keywords.text];
self.link.text = terms;
```

Apologies if this question is a no-brainer, I'm new to Objective C. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is your target method being called? If yes, try and log the text as it changes, and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to set the delegate of the UITextField to self, and implement the delegate method like this.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;
{
    if ([string length]) {
        self.theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"q=%@%@", textField.text,string];
    } else {
        self.theLabel.text = [self.theLabel.text substringToIndex:self.theLabel.text.length - 1];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Another way to do this is observe the text changes using NSNotification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeLabelText:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];


- (void)changeLabelText:(id)sender
{
   self.theLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"q=%@", self.textField.text];
}
```

Comment: This works well, although there is an issue of when you delete all characters manually that are entered, that it leaves the very first character behind. Do you know why this is occurring?

Comment: It is because textField's text changes after this method is returned YES, so when you delete a character, `(NSString *)string` is an empty string, which is supposed to replace the last character of the textField's text. Suppose you have "abc" as the text, you delete a character expecting "ab", but at the point  setting label text, textField.text is still "abc", string is "", so you still see "abc" in the label.

Comment: I see, is there any possible workaround for this issue?